# Using send_mail in Django: Cannot display data in invoice from functions

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, sendmail

another Django send_mail question. Seems like I have problems displaying data in an email that separate form from function. Seems like this is a variable problem.

**Edit:** I manage to make the client name show up! Now how can to the same thing with invoice. Say that I wanted to display the date, invoice_no, work_orders & contract_info?

```
    #models.py
    class Invoice(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    date = models.DateField()
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    work_orders = models.ManyToManyField(Work_Order)
    contract_info = models.ForeignKey(Contract_Info)

    def __unicode__(self):
                return self.invoice_no

    #views.py
    @login_required
    def invoice_mail(request, id=1):
        invoices_list = Invoice.objects.filter(pk=id)
        client = invoices_list[0].client
        t = loader.get_template('registration/email.txt')
        c = Context({
        'client': client.company,
        })
        send_mail('Welcome to My Project', t.render(c), 'jess@example.com', ['mark@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return render_to_response('email.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my email.txt

```
Dear {{client}},
```

And when I send it to my email account I receive this

Dear Currys,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing to do with send_mail. You are sending this to your template context"

```
c = Context({
    'invoice': 'invoice.client',
    })
```

Here 'invoice' is a string containing the text 'invoice.client'. You need to send an actual object. However your naming is unclear, so I can't tell whether you want to send the Invoice object, or the related Client.

Comment: I want to to see whatever in {{invoice.client}} data to be able to be displayed in the email

Comment: Well then, send `invoice.client` rather than `'invoice.client'`.

Comment: I get an error "global name 'invoice' is not defined". I believe the invoice they are talking is in invoice.client. Not 'invoice'

Comment: You *really* have to sort out your naming conventions. If you want to send the client, send the client, but don't call it 'invoice'.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel has already pointed out.

```
c = Context({
    'client': 'client.company',
})
```

Needs to be:

```
c = Context({
    'client': client.company,
})
```

When you wrap something in '' it becomes a string, not the object it was pointing to.

Comment: Whoops. actually that just a typo. I have worked out that problem but I guess I did not update properly. I do it now.